# Geometry Nodes: How to simulate rotation achieved with "Distribute points on Face" when using a "resample Curve" of edges extracted from a mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to achieve the effect of the below nodes setup combined togheter, distribution of points taken from "resample curve" node and the rotation taken from "distribute points on Faces" node.

Correct distribution but wrong rotation of instances:
[image: Result 1]
[image: Resample Curve, Wrong rotations of instances, but correct distribution]

Correct rotation but wrong distribution of Instances:
[image: Result 2]
[image: Distribute points on Faces, Wrong distribution of instances, but correct rotation]

The problem is that i cannot use points from curve and plug in the rotation from Distribute Points on Faces node.

Is there a way to achieve what i want?

Comment: Would you mind showing the base geometry you get from the input? Or maybe upload a file? Because maybe there is something different in your file which is not visible in the screenshots so that the answer proposed by Crantisz does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can grab a normal from the nearest surface point from the mesh and convert it to rotation using align Euler to Vector node:

[image]

Two Align to Vector nodes makes it aligned horizontally also:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seems to work for my case. this is the result https://imgur.com/7cZU3eG

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, see if that helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQdT5kACMQc